# Opposite of disciplined with positive or neutral connotations

Tags: antonyms, nonsubjective

Is there a word or phrase that means the opposite of disciplined, but which doesn't have negative connotations?

Comment: Perhaps ‘creative’? Otherwise, you may have to go for a phrase, rather than a word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps **free-spirited** is what you want:

> free spirit n. One who is not restrained, as by convention or
>   obligation; a nonconformist.

[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/free+spirit)

However, I'd say that "the opposite of 'disciplined' ", if one can be agreed upon, is bound to have negative overtones because 'disciplined' has positive ones.

Comment: In the same vein, perhaps ‘unbridled’.

Comment: The problem is 'discipline' is a loaded word. And people have such radically different ideas, from those who think the best upbringing they ever got was in the army, to those who think excessive discipline makes Jack a dull boy.

Comment: @WS2: Yes; among infinitely polysemic words (ie words), 'discipline' is more infinitely polysemic than many. Which makes 'What is the / an opposite of ...?' virtually unanswerable objectively.

Answer (score 2):

*Spontaneous*, perhaps. It's usually regarded as a positive word, but also implies a lack of discipline.

Comment: I really liked this answer too

Answer (score 1):

As hinted at in Edwin Ashworth's good answer, consider also **[unrestrained](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unrestrained)**

> Not restrained or restricted: *a display of unrestrained delight*

It can be used positively, negatively or neutrally.

Another term that can have a range of inflections is **[wild](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wild)**.  While it often has a pejorative tone, it can be used in an admiring way

> unconventional; fantastic; crazy: *wild friends*

It also can be used [neutrally](https://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/wild)

> Lacking regular order or arrangement; disarranged: *wild locks of long hair*.

Answer (score 1):

A person who doesn't behave in a ritual manner or doesn't follow a fixed routine could be described as being ***easygoing***. It usually carries very positive connotations, and implies the person is patient and tolerant, whereas *disciplined* can suggest intolerance and inflexibility.

[Easygoing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/easygoing): *Not rigorous, demanding, or stressful: "an easygoing life as a part-time consultant."*

Answer (score 0):

Undisciplined does not work for you?

Or how about: lax

M&W:
2 : deficient in firmness : not stringent

Comment: ‘Lax’ and ‘undisciplined’ both tend to have negative connotations.